# Pass Woocommerce Order ID into filter in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to add some additional information to the "order-completed"-Email in Woocommerce. I have tried several solutions but it seems that I just can't get the order-id.

What I tried for e.g.:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_heading_customer_completed_order','getWC_order_details');
function getWC_order_details( $order ) {
    $test = var_dump( $order->id );
    return $test;
}
```

Always getting NULL or bool(false), what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [in the source](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/1b38f380af07b3af91f4f334ffac33780abd60f1/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-completed-order.php#L86), that filter takes two parameters: (1) the heading text, (2) the order object. You must also explicitly specify that in your functions:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_heading_customer_completed_order','getWC_order_details', 10, 2);
function getWC_order_details( $heading, $order ) {
    $test = var_dump( $order->id );
    return $test;
}
```